# DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER while using environment variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssis, database-administration

I have an SSIS package that uses parameterised connection managers that read the connection string from environment variables.Following is one of the connection string that I am using in the environment variable.

```
Data Source=JCODERPC;Initial Catalog=DevDestination;Integrated Security=True;Application Name=SSIS-TestParameterisedConnection-{04CFECB8-52A9-467C-9DFD-13BA9F8700C1}JCODERPC.Test;
```

But I am getting error while running the package.

> Data Flow task:Error:SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.

[image]

Can anybody help me in solving this.

Comment: did you checked connection manager that has permissions to the destination i.e shared folder/file ?

Comment: @Jyothish you have to set the `DelayValidation` property to true for the `DataFlow Task`

Comment: I got the issue resolved. But I dont know the correct scenario. When I click parameterize option there is a radio button to created new variable. If I create variables using that option, then no error. Other wise if we create a varaible in server, it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Reading destination table name from a variable can throw this error, if the initial value of the variable is NULL or it contains an invalid table name.

You have to set `DelayValidation` to `True` on the tasks that use the connection.

---

*Note: From the image you provided it looks like you have to change it for the DataFlow Task, just click on the DataFlow Task, press `F4` to show the properties Tab, then change this property to `True`*